# What does it mean an histogram vector normalization with L1/L2 norms?

Tags: clustering, image-processing, computer-vision

I was reading [these](http://www.di.ens.fr/willow/events/cvml2011/materials/CVML2011_Cordelia_bof.pdf) slides about Bag of Features (BoF). At slide 23 you can read:

> each image is represented by a vector, typically 1000-4000 dimension,
> **normalization with L1/L2 norm**

What does the bold phrase means?

Comment: I know what that L2 Eucledian distance is. I don't know what **normalize an histogram with such a norm means**

Comment: I just noticed that the title is incompleate, I'm sorry for that

Comment: @Tim and I answered your previous question, and now you are bringing a new question. Really, you shouldn't post updates. Post these as new questions instead.

Comment: You're right. If you're still interested to answer, look at [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/224757/why-should-we-normalized-bag-of-features-histograms) question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$L_p$ normalization is actually described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_of_oriented_gradients#Block_normalization) that quotes [Dalal
and Triggs (2005)](http://lear.inrialpes.fr/people/triggs/pubs/Dalal-cvpr05.pdf)

> Dalal and Triggs explored four different methods for block
>   normalization. Let $v$ be the non-normalized vector containing all
>   histograms in a given block, $\|v\|_k$ be its $k$-norm for $k={1,2}$
>   and $e$ be some small constant (the exact value, hopefully, is
>   unimportant). Then the normalization factor can be one of the
>   following:
>
> L2-norm: $f = {v \over \sqrt{\|v\|^2_2+e^2}}$
>
> (...)
>
> L1-norm: $f = {v \over (\|v\|_1+e)}$
>
> L1-sqrt: $f = \sqrt{v \over (\|v\|_1+e)}$

So $L_p$ normalization of histograms in fact relates to using [$L_p$ norms](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163388/l2-regularization-is-equivalent-to-gaussian-prior) to normalize vectors.

By "dimensions" authors mean the "length" of vectors.

---

Dalal, N., & Triggs, B. (2005). [Histograms of oriented gradients for human detection.](http://lear.inrialpes.fr/people/triggs/pubs/Dalal-cvpr05.pdf) In 2005 IEEE Computer Society Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition (CVPR'05) (Vol. 1, pp. 886-893). IEEE.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ok, should be unimportant, but some suggestion about the value of $e$?

Comment: Please, look also at my **UPDATE**

Comment: @user6321 you **changed** your question to different one - please do not to that. You should rather accept one of the answers (it they answer your initial question) and start a **new** question.

Comment: You're right. If you're still interested to answer, look at [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/224757/why-should-we-normalized-bag-of-features-histograms) question.

Comment: @user6321 thanks :) This makes this site much better organized and in fact makes you **more** likely to receive answer to the new question because people may be less prone to look at edited question then to check the new question (such new question would be also longer visible on the list of new questions comparing to the edited one).

Comment: You're welcome :D Should [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/224764/bag-of-features-why-the-distance-between-two-histograms-of-the-same-image-is-di) question be posted on stackoverflow (since it's about programming)?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if I had to guess what the slide is referring to:

- $L_{2}$ normalization
  $$x_i'=\frac{x_i}{\|x\|_2}=\frac{x_i}{\left(\sum_j{x_j^2}\right)^{1/2}}$$
- $L_{1}$ normalization
  $$x_i'=\frac{x_i}{\|x\|_1}=\frac{x_i}{\sum_j{|x_j|}}$$

---

The $L^{p}$ norm is given by $\|x\|_{p}=\sqrt[p]{\sum_i|x_i|^{p}}, p \in \mathbb{R}$ ([link](https://rorasa.wordpress.com/2012/05/13/l0-norm-l1-norm-l2-norm-l-infinity-norm/)).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your annotation. $x_i$ is a the i-th vector? Or is it the i_th dimension of vector x?

Comment: Is it a *guess* or an answer?

Comment: @Tim it's an answer, because that's the definition of the $L^{p}$ norm, but it's a guess because I'm not sure that's what the slide is referring to.

Comment: @user6321 $x_i$ is the $i$-th position of the $x$ vector, yes. See the denominator is the norm I refer to.

Comment: An answer. Actually, it is the same as used in loss-regularization techniques for example.

Of course, in other fields, other L-norms exists (say, more general definitions), but regarding ML this is the commonly used one.

Comment: Ok, I hink that there was an error in the answer before the editing :)

Comment: @user6321 no, there wasn't, I just clarified the norm in the denominator and notation, no other modifications.

Comment: Please, look also at my **UPDATE**