# Bag of Features: why the distance between two histograms of the same image is different than 0?

Tags: clustering, histogram, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to implement a Content Based Image Retrieval application for small image datasets. I'm testing it just with 1 thousands images from [Caltech1001](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/Image_Datasets/Caltech101/).

The approach that I'm using is the classic Bag of Features model using OpenCV using `k`-means and `cv::SIFT` detector/descriptor and `HISTCMP_CHISQR_ALT` as distance metric. Just for testing purpose, I tried to use as a query **one image from the dataset itself**, so the distance should be 0. This is the relative code:

```
cv::Mat vocabulary; //fill vocabulary through k-Means
cv::Mat histograms;
cv::Mat imgHistogram;
cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorMatcher> matcher(new cv::BFMatcher);
std::unique_ptr<cv::BOWImgDescriptorExtractor> bowDE = 
     std::make_unique<cv::BOWImgDescriptorExtractor> (featureDetectorDescriptor,matcher);
std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keyPoints;
//Compute histograms for all dataset images 
bowDE->setVocabulary(vocabulary);
for (each img in the dataset){
    featureDetectorDescriptor->detect(img, keyPoints);
    bowDE->compute(img,keyPoints,word);
    histograms.push_back(word);
}
//Compute the word of one image img FROM THE DATASET ITSELF!
featureDetectorDescriptor->detect(img, keyPoints);
bowDE->compute(img,keyPoints,imgHistogram);
double mindist = DBL_MAX;
for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
    double dist = compareHist(imgHistogram, histograms.row(i), cv::HISTCMP_CHISQR_ALT );
    if(dist<minDist)
        minDist = dist;
}
```

Ok, since the query image `img` is contained in the database itself, the most similar returned is `img` itself, **but minDist is different from 0!** For example, for one image the distance from herself is `0.0119228`.

And these are the relative histograms:

`img` in `histogram`:

```
[0.0059701493, 0.0089552235, 0.052238807, 0.0014925373, 0.0029850747, 0.016417911, 0.0014925373, 0.0014925373, 0.0014925373, 0.0014925373, 0.011940299, 0.0074626869, 0.0014925373, 0.0044776117, 0.0029850747, 0.0044776117, 0.011940299, 0.014925374, 0.12985075, 0.0044776117, 0.0014925373, 0.0074626869, 0, 0.0029850747, 0.0014925373, 0.013432836, 0.0074626869, 0.011940299, 0.0029850747, 0.0014925373, 0.061194029, 0.013432836, 0.0059701493, 0.0029850747, 0, 0.0014925373, 0.0074626869, 0.0014925373, 0.0059701493, 0.0029850747, 0.0029850747, 0.0029850747, 0.0059701493, 0, 0.025373135, 0.017910447, 0.0044776117, 0.0044776117, 0.0044776117, 0.0014925373, 0.0014925373, 0.0074626869, 0.010447761, 0.014925374, 0.0044776117, 0.0029850747, 0.0059701493, 0.055223882, 0.0029850747, 0, 0.0089552235, 0.0029850747, 0.0074626869, 0.0044776117, 0.0074626869, 0.0089552235, 0.0059701493, 0.0014925373, 0.020895522, 0, 0, 0.014925374, 0.019402985, 0.0029850747, 0.0044776117, 0, 0.0089552235, 0.0029850747, 0.0029850747, 0.0029850747, 0, 0.0014925373, 0.016417911, 0, 0.010447761, 0.017910447, 0.013432836, 0.0089552235, 0.0014925373, 0.011940299, 0.019402985, 0.010447761, 0.0059701493, 0.059701495, 0.031343285, 0.016417911, 0.011940299, 0.0014925373, 0.010447761, 0.0044776117]
```

`img` as query:

```
[0.0061349692, 0.0092024542, 0.053680979, 0.0015337423, 0.0030674846, 0.016871165, 0.0015337423, 0.0015337423, 0.0015337423, 0.0015337423, 0.010736196, 0.0076687112, 0.0015337423, 0.0046012271, 0.0030674846, 0.0046012271, 0.012269938, 0.016871165, 0.12423313, 0.0046012271, 0.0015337423, 0.0076687112, 0, 0.0030674846, 0.0015337423, 0.01380368, 0.0076687112, 0.012269938, 0.0030674846, 0, 0.06134969, 0.01380368, 0.0061349692, 0.0030674846, 0, 0.0015337423, 0.0076687112, 0, 0.0061349692, 0.0030674846, 0.0015337423, 0.0030674846, 0.0061349692, 0, 0.02607362, 0.010736196, 0.0046012271, 0.0046012271, 0.0046012271, 0.0015337423, 0.0015337423, 0.0076687112, 0.010736196, 0.015337422, 0.0046012271, 0.0015337423, 0.0061349692, 0.053680979, 0.0030674846, 0, 0.0092024542, 0.0030674846, 0.0076687112, 0.0046012271, 0.0076687112, 0.0092024542, 0.0076687112, 0.0015337423, 0.021472393, 0, 0, 0.015337422, 0.023006134, 0.0030674846, 0.0030674846, 0, 0.010736196, 0.0030674846, 0.0030674846, 0.0030674846, 0, 0.0015337423, 0.016871165, 0, 0.010736196, 0.018404908, 0.012269938, 0.0092024542, 0.0015337423, 0.012269938, 0.021472393, 0.010736196, 0.0061349692, 0.059815951, 0.030674845, 0.015337422, 0.012269938, 0.0015337423, 0.010736196, 0.0046012271]
```

This means that the first histogram computed for `img` and then saved in `histogram` is different from `imgHistogram`!

How is this possible? The two histograms should be the same!

**Notice** that this is true also for other distances like `HISTCMP_CHISQR` or `HISTCMP_HELLINGER`.

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable enough to answer this question, but is the method completely deterministic? (it looks like it's not to me)

Comment: It is strange indeed. @Firebug, it is a completely deterministic method. I'd say the problem is something related to feature normalization. Do you know if any normalization across data points is performed? (i.e., "column-wise" normalization, if the rows of your data matrix contain the histograms)