# Why deep learning prefer the probability distribution with a sharp point?

Tags: probability, distributions, deep-learning, exponential-distribution, laplace-distribution

I am reading Ian Goodfellow's book about deep learning and when it introduces exponential distribution, it says "In the context of deep learning, we often want to have a probability distribution with a sharp point at x=0." I don't understand why the probability distribution should have this character, does it help to train the model?
[image: The book is Goodfellow's Deep Learning]

Comment: Neither density is differentiable at the cusp point ($0$ for the first, $\mu$ for the second). You can see the sharpness from a plot. Why this is useful in deep learning, I have no idea. I can't really help you there. But also, I take issue with the author's use of the word "mass."

Comment: @Taylor "mass" is standard terminology in probability.

Comment: @Taylor I think "mass" is a typo. The correct one should be "density" because Laplace distribution is a continuous probability distribution.

Comment: cf the relationship between lasso and pinning some coefficient estimates at exactly 0.

Comment: In what context is the distribution used?

Answer (score 1):

These two distribution have a connection with deep learning via regularisation. In deep learning we are often concerned with regularising the parameters of a neural network because neural networks tend to overfit and we want to improve ability of the model to generalise to new data.

From a Bayesian perspective, fitting a regularised model can be interpreted as computing the maximum a posteriori (MAP) estimate given a specific prior distribution over the weights $w_i$. In particular,

- the $L^2$ (a.k.a. weight decay) norm  corresponds to a Gaussian prior on the weights $w$, and
- the $L^1$ norm corresponds to an isotropic Laplace prior over the weights $w$.

The $L^1$ norm (a.k.a. the Laplace prior on weights) by virtue of it's sharpness encourages sparsity (many zeros) in $w$ for reasons explained here: [Why L1 norm for sparse models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45643/why-l1-norm-for-sparse-models) . This type of regularisation can be quite desirable. The connection between the Laplacian distribution and the $L^1$ norm is explained in more detail here: [Why is Lasso penalty equivalent to the double exponential (Laplace) prior?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/182098/why-is-lasso-penalty-equivalent-to-the-double-exponential-laplace-prior)

Most of what I have mentioned here is discussed in more detail in the same "Deep Learning" book in section 5.6.1 and section 7.1.2.