# If LASSO is equivalent to Bayesian Regression with a Laplace (double exponential) prior, what would be the prior for non-negative LASSO? Exponential?

Tags: bayesian, lasso, regularization, prior, exponential-distribution

We know that the LASSO penalty is equivalent to Laplace prior. So what would be the corresponding prior for a non-negative LASSO? Is it exponential distribution?
More generally, is it true that every constraint can be translated into a prior distribution under the Bayesian framework? Then if we have constraints like sparse, non-negative, smoothness, etc., what will be the strategy to find the corresponding Bayesian prior?
I know this might be too general, but I believe I am not the first one to consider this question. Any suggestions/references/papers will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can copy the situation from [Why is Lasso penalty equivalent to the double exponential (Laplace) prior?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/182098/why-is-lasso-penalty-equivalent-to-the-double-exponential-laplace-prior)

We minimize the loss

$$L(\beta \vert X, y) = \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-f(\beta,X_i))^2 + \lambda \sum_{i=1}^p \vert \beta_i \vert $$

which is like maximizing

$$e^{-L(\beta \vert X, y)} = e^{- \frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-f(\beta,X_i))^2} \cdot  e^{-\frac{\lambda}{2\sigma^2}  \sum_{i=1}^p \vert \beta_p \vert } $$

And appart from some scaling constant (to normalize the function) this can be seen as equal to the posterior distribution when it is the product of the likelihood of a Gaussian distribution and the prior distribution for the coefficients which is proportional to

$$f_{\text{prior}} \propto e^{-\frac{\lambda}{2\sigma^2}   \sum_{i=1}^p \vert \beta_i \vert }$$

---

With non-negative lasso this cost function remains the same (except that we do not allow negative coefficients $\beta_i$)

So we can keep the same Laplace form of the prior function, and need to change it only when $\beta_i$ are negative.

$$f_{\text{prior}} \propto \begin{cases}
e^{-\lambda \sum_{i=1}^p \vert \beta_i \vert } & \quad \text{if $\forall i: \beta_i \geq 0$} \\
0 & \quad \text{if $\exists i: \beta_i < 0$} \\
\end{cases}$$

Which is indeed just like the exponential distribution as prior.

---

In the case of constraints on smoothness they will end up in the distribution of the prior. For instance if you have some extra constraint which is a function of the $\beta$

$$L(\beta \vert X, y) = \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-f(\beta,X_i))^2 + \lambda_1 \sum_{i=1}^p \vert \beta_i \vert + \lambda_2 g(\beta)$$

then this will end up as an exponential term in the prior distribution

$$f_{\text{prior}} \propto e^{-\frac{\lambda_1}{2\sigma^2}   \sum_{i=1}^p \vert \beta_i \vert -\frac{\lambda_2}{2\sigma^2} g(\beta) }$$

In this case you may not so easily get a simple prior distribution like the $$e^{-\frac{\lambda}{2\sigma^2}   \sum_{i=1}^p \vert \beta_i \vert} =e^{-\frac{\lambda}{2\sigma^2}   \vert \beta_1 \vert} \cdot e^{-\frac{\lambda}{2\sigma^2}   \vert \beta_2 \vert} \cdot e^{-\frac{\lambda}{2\sigma^2}   \vert \beta_3 \vert} \cdot \dots  $$ which partitions into independent distributions for the individual $\beta_i$.

For instance for fused Lasso, in which case the differences of neighbours $\vert \beta_{i+1} -\beta_{i} \vert$ are included in the penalty, you would get something like the following (for only two coefficients)

$$f_{\text{prior}} \propto e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} \left( \lambda_1    \vert \beta_1 \vert  +\lambda_1    \vert \beta_2 \vert + \lambda_2   \vert \beta_2 - \beta_1 \vert  \right) }$$